# If $[L:M]=[L:M´]$ and $M´ \subseteq M$ then $M=M´$

Tags: galois-theory

I´m studying the proof of the primitive element in abstract algebra. In some part of the proof, the book says that, as we have $[L:M]=[L:M´]$ and $M´ \subseteq M$ then $M=M´$. I´m trying to prove it, but I´m stuck. How can you prove it? $[L:M]$ is the dimension of $L$ as a $M$-vector space and we have $K \subseteq M´ \subseteq M \subseteq L$.

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since $[L:M'] = [L:M] \times [M:M']$. So, $[M:M'] = 1$ which means $M = M'$.

Comment: Assuming all the vector space dimensions are finite, otherwise you may have problem (to conclude). (Though in this situation, probably all the extensions are finite; so nothing to worry about.)